# How to support Forward Secrecy in OpenSSL

Tags: tls, openssl

I build openssl-1.0.2l
I used in my https server

I tried to test my https server with ssllabs. The ssllabs returns the following warning:

```
The server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers
```

can I fix that in the build options of openssl ?

Comment: lots of online tutorials: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-enabling-perfect-forward-secrecy.htm

Answer (score 1):

> can I fix that in the build options of openssl ?

The problem is not your OpenSSL build but the configuration of your unknown server. In order to enable forward secrecy you need to enabled ECDHE and/or DH cipher suites in the server configuration.

For examples of recommended configurations see [Security/Server Side TLS](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS).

Comment: s/DH/DHE/. Also 1.0.2 needs setting `tmp_dh` or `tmp_ecdh` parameters or `ecdh_auto` mode at libssl level (these vary some with other OpenSSL versions) and whether the server application level defaults that for you or requires config varies.